# Como fazer uma quebra de linha com jquery?

Tags: jquery

estou com um textarea, e na hora que você digita o texto vai aparecendo na imagem html entendem?
Tipo isso[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como posso fazer meu texto quebrar la na outra div a partir do momento que eu dê um enter no textarea.Com Jquery.

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML e explicar a relação entre digitar texto, textarea e a imagem?

Comment: você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Isso vai te ajudar bastante https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Outra leitura indispensável https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2):

Use a tag `pre` dentro da div.

[**`<pre> - HTML | MDN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) é a tag utilizada para representar texto pré-formatado. Um texto dentro desse elemento é tipicamente exibido em uma fonte não proporcional da mesma maneira em que o texto original foi disposto no arquivo. Espaços em branco são mantidos no texto da mesma forma em que este foi digitado.

```js
$(function() {
    $origem=$("#origem");
    $saida=$("#saida");
    $origem.keyup(function() {
       $saida.text($origem.val());
    });
});
```

```css
body { color:#ffffff}

#origem { width:250px; height:5em;}

#saida { 
    font-family: Arial Black; font-size: 14px;
}

.imagemDeFundo{
    background: url('https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/textura-do-grunge-do-quadro-negro-36176292.jpg') no-repeat; 
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="origem"></textarea>
<div class="imagemDeFundo"><pre id="saida"></pre></div>
```